Working up to Etale Cohomology.
I'm familiar with most of the "basic course" material of Algebraic Geometry from Qing Liu's book, and am planning on reading Milne's book (not lecture notes) on Etale cohomology as my next steps. However, he lists a few other prerequisites, such as galois cohomology, basic homological algebra and homotopy and fundamental groups, and I don't want to spend an inordinate amount of time retracing these things amidst a lot of other background.
What would you say are the best resources to quickly satisfy these prerequisites? Otherwise, what would your alternative suggestions be?

Milne writes the following about the prerequisites in his lecture notes (not the book) on etale cohomology: There is a summary of these topics in my Class Field Theory notes, pp 69–76, and complete presentations in several books, for example, in
Weibel, C.A., An Introduction to Homological Algebra, Cambridge U.P., 1994. This is an excellent suggestion, by someone who knows it.
